# Quartz Scheduler - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: exception, quartz-scheduler, classnotfound

I am using Quratz 1.6.3 API in a Maven project. This is the error message I get when I run it:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/SetUtils
 at org.quartz.JobDetail.(JobDetail.java:85)
.....

commons.collections 3.2 dependency is included in the project's pom.xml file. What could be the reason for this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

commons.collections 3.2.1 contains this class

```
org\apache\commons\collections\SetUtils.class
```

So the problem should be in your maven project. Double check that the commons.collections gets is the classpath (see logs). Or show the project configuration, so we would be able to help.